# android supplicant

Tags: android, wifi

these days, i am trying to porting wifi to my board, the android version is JellyBean,the linux kernel is 2.6.35.11, the dirver is realtek rtl8192, i config the kernel supported wifi an make it,now it's turn to complie the driver,i also config the makefile,now it support my board,and i got the applicant "rel_supplciant(the makefile build it in this name)" in the directory "/system/bin" on my board,now i run the apllicant rel_supplicant,but it doesn't work,i catch the logcat,it said like this:

```
I/wpa_supplicant( 1794): rfkill: Cannot open RFKILL control device
E/wpa_supplicant( 1794): nl80211: Could not configure driver to use managed mode
E/wpa_supplicant( 1794): Could not read interface p2p0 flags: No such device
E/wpa_supplicant( 1794): p2p0: Failed to initialize driver interface
```

you maybe curious about the log,yes this is the JellyBean's new properties,if you want to start supplicant,you need to create two interface "wlan0" and "p2p0" one by one,only they're all created,the supplicant can be started right.

the problem here is when i run the supplicant "rel_supplicant" is directroy "/system/bin" on my board,the supplicant cann't be started,I don't konw why.if the supplicant can't be start by cmd,that is to say,it cann't be started from the init.rc

Comment: Please rephrase your text, this is unreadable.

Comment: The applicant rel_supplicant cann't be start by 

cmd "rel_supplicant -ip2p0 -Dnl80211 -c/data/misc/wifi/p2p_supplicant.conf \
    -e/data/misc/wifi/entropy.bin -N \
    -iwlan0 -Dnl80211 -c/data/misc/wifi/wpa_supplicant.conf"

i'm sure the conf file is right, but i don't know why the supplciant can not be started? is my driver builed wrong? I'm come from China,this is the first time i search for help from stackoverflow.com, so Maybe i don't give a clear description.